# Is there a way to use a getExistingDirectory for folders with the same view that getOpenFileName uses

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I've made a small app to convert folders into CBZ format, but when prompting the user to select a folder, the QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory method uses a tree view that I really don't like. The getOpenFileName have a standard view of the filesystem, but it only works for files and not directories.

My idea is to:

1. Make getExistingDirectory change it's view mode
2. Use or some getOpenFileName variation to load folders

I've tried using TK instead for the file dialog, but it is even worse on UI terms, so it's a no go for me.

Setting FileMode to Directory seems to not work at all (or maybe I'm doing something wrong, but the docs are really bad for that).

Comment: As stated in the [QFileDialog docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getExistingDirectory), you can use the `DontUseNativeDialog` option.

Comment: @ekhumoro I've changed machines, and this seems to not happen on my desktop (only on laptop) Maybe is a system config bug. Sadly I don't have the laptop now, but I will test it there to see if it work.

Comment: @TallysAssis Consider using a full instance of QFileDialog, and apply the proper [filter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#setFilter) (`QDir.Dirs`).

Comment: @ekhumoro doing that worked quite well. I'll put it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Following ekhumoro's suggestion and using the DontUseNativeDialog worked. It may look bad on Gnome, but on Plasma it looks better.

This is the line to call the dialog:

```
self.folder = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, 'Abrir pasta', home_directory, QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)
```